# PG::ConnectionBad FATAL: role "BetBook3" is not permitted to log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am getting the above error when entering localhost:3000 into the browser.  I have attempted to restart the browser but this did not work.

This is the stack trace from the server console in Rubymine:

```
PG::ConnectionBad (FATAL:  role "BetBook3" is not permitted to log in
):
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213:in `initialize'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213:in `new'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213:in `connect'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:329:in `initialize'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:309:in `new_connection'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:319:in `checkout_new_connection'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `loop'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `block in checkout'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:233:in `checkout'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:96:in `block in connection'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `connection'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:404:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:170:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:144:in `connection'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__555291250__call__204891181__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

I have been following this tutorial to the point where I deleted the defalt homepage and routed to my own:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/575551/User-Authentication-in-Ruby-on-Rails

Comment: You have to setup the postgres DB role you specified in your database.yml file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The error message explains the problem.

```
 ALTER ROLE "BetBook3" WITH LOGIN;
```